# sql best way finding all results presents in two tables with a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, compare

im beginner at sql, hope you can help me :

MYSQL SERVER 5

**table1**

```
+----+----------+------------+------+
| ID | USERCODE | ENTITYCODE | DATE |
+----+----------+------------+------+
|  x | CODE123  |     010011 | ...  |
|  x | CODE123  |     010012 | ...  |
|  x | CODE123  |     010045 | ...  |
+----+----------+------------+------+
```

**table2**

```
+----+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| ID | USERCODE | ENTITYCODE | OTHERFIELD1 | OTHERFIELD2 |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| x  | CODE123  | 010011     | ...         | ...         |
| x  | CODE123  | 010012     | ...         | ...         |
| x  | CODE123  | 010045     | ...         | ...         |
| .. | ..       | ..         | ...         | ...         |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**entity table**

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ENTITYCODE | OTHERFIELD1 | OTHERFIELD2 | SPECIALCODE |
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 010011     | ..          | ..          | 100         |
| 010012     | ..          | ..          | 105         |
| 010045     | ..          | ..          | 111         |
| ..         | ..          | ...         | ...         |
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Expected result**

Constraint : all the USERCODE,ENTITY CODE present in table1, table2 and entity.specialcode = 105

```
+-----------+------------+
| USERCODE  | ENTITYCODE |
+-----------+------------+
| CODE123   |     010012 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.USERCODE , a.ENTITYCODE
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.USERCODE = b.USERCODE AND a.ENTITYCODE = b.ENTITYCODE
JOIN entity c ON a.ENTITYCODE = c.ENTITYCODE
WHERE c.SPECIALCODE = 105
```

Comment: thx a lot , it works like a charm , i wrote the same request but using INNER join duplicates results

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT USERCODE,ENTITYCODE FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ENTITYCODE = table2.ENTITYCODE
INNER JOIN entity ON entity.ENTITYCODE = table1.ENTITYCODE
WHERE SPECIALCODE = 105
```

Refer :

- [Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)
- [mysql-using-joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: didn't works, i got duplicates rows in results and i m not sure distinct is the best way ...

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle.com link with sample data